# Confusion why a magic 1.6 user cannot find app on market

Tags: android, google-play

I've published an app today mainly for my forum users to use, just a
very simple app that displays wallpapers derived from the forum.

Problem I'm having is one guy says it doesn't appear in the market,
and I've even sent him the APK to install manually but it fails.

My minimum SDK version is 4, I created it with the 1.6 SDK specified
so not sure why he can't see it or install it.  He has a 1.6 Magic
handset.

So just wondering if anyone has any ideas,  the app is called bocn
wallpaper, it uses internet and set-wallpaper permissions.. but I
wouldn't have thought the permissions were the problem...

My manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" package="net.dbws.bocnwallpaper">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:value="xxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" /> 
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: If you're still having an issue, add a bounty to the question.  If it went away on its own, fine.  But please don't select a non-answer as the answer.

Comment: @Makoto, Your edit of removing the "thanks" and removing the tag "magic" wasn't very helpful in this case. You probably didn't notice it, I've made the very same mistake myself, but this post is 5 years old!  Editing a very old question like that has the side-effect of bumping it back up to the top of the list of recent questions, which is not what we want.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk There's nothing wrong with the edit going back to the front page; that's why it does that.  I did edit the question knowing this full and well.  The magic tag's removal can be seen http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295011/1079354.

Comment: @Makoto, Ah ok. My mistake I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the supported screens: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Android 1.6 has small-screens flag set default to false. May be it causes that the application is not seen on the device of the guy.

Comment: Ahh that might be it.. I'll give it a go.. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Althought from what I've just read on that page, from API level 4, All screens ARE supported by default. Back to the drawing board ;-)

Comment: Strange... from 2.1 I see your application. What about posting your manifest here? There is another opportunity: may be you didn't set the  "All locations" check box in developers console?

Comment: had to add it to my initial question